# Get total duration of Audio /Video file before upload for multiple files?

Tags: javascript, audio, javascript-objects

> This will help me in getting the duration for a single audio file if I have multiple audio files uploaded I should be able to find the total audio length od those uploaded files.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      File: <input type="file" name="fup" id="fup" /><br>
      Duration: <input type="text" name="f_du" id="f_du" size="5" /> seconds<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <audio id="audio"></audio>

    <script>
    // Code to get duration of audio /video file before upload - from: http://coursesweb.net/

    //register canplaythrough event to #audio element to can get duration
    var f_duration =0;  //store duration
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(e){
      //add duration in the input field #f_du
      f_duration = Math.round(e.currentTarget.duration);
      document.getElementById('f_du').value = f_duration;
      URL.revokeObjectURL(obUrl);
    });

    //when select a file, create an ObjectURL with the file and add it in the #audio element
    var obUrl;
    document.getElementById('fup').addEventListener('change', function(e){
      var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
      //check file extension for audio/video type
      if(file.name.match(/\.(avi|mp3|mp4|mpeg|ogg)$/i)){
        obUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        document.getElementById('audio').setAttribute('src', obUrl);
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your script

Comment: But when I add multiple files it's not giving the total time?? @oviemoses